# DateTime.ToString issue

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, tostring

I try to display a `DateTime` with the "general date short time" format.
When I use the `g` specifier, it gives me something like `01-08-13 10:12:00 10:12` instead of `01-05-13 10:12`.

It seems to duplicate the time and I don't know why.

Anyone?

**Edit 1**
Here is the code I use:

```
var startDate = DateTime.MinValue.ToString("g");  
if (Airspace.StartDate != null)  
    startDate = ((DateTime)Airspace.StartDate).ToString("g"); //01-08-13 00:00:00 00:00
```

**Edit 2**
The same issue occurs when I use "short date pattern":

```
var startDate = DateTime.MinValue.ToString("d");  
if (Airspace.StartDate != null)  
    startDate = ((DateTime)Airspace.StartDate).ToString("d"); //01-08-13 00:00:00
```

It doesn't make sense!

Comment: I use C# language and .net Framework 4.0.

Comment: Please post the portion of the code where you are doing this. The question does not have enough information.

Comment: There must be something in your code. Here is a nice reference by the way: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: Does .toShortDateString, not work?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder, No it Doesn't. It does not give me the desired format and still add `00:00:00` at the end.

Comment: where does it duplicate?In the first statement or the third one?The first startdate prints in the format "1/1/2001 12:00 AM".

Comment: While in debugging mode, when I place my mouse over the `startDate` variable, it shows me `01-01-0001 00:00:00 00:00`. The issue seems to appear both when I use `DateTime.MinValue` or `Airspace.StartDate`

Comment: What's the type of `Airspace.StartDate`? You're casting to `DateTime` so that might be part of the issue.

Comment: Airspace.StartDate is `DateTime?`. Yes, that might be but the issue alors occurs with a `DateTime`.

Comment: That cast should be fine then. Never comes across this issue before. Try avoiding the explicit cast and do this `startDate = Airspace.StartDate.Value.ToString("g");`

Comment: Same result. It might be noticeable that when the value comes from the database (Access + ADO.NET), it does not contain `00:00:00` and displays correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help you:

```
  DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
  Console.WriteLine(today.ToString("dd-MM-yy H:mm"));
  //Result: 01-08-13 04:33
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Other format: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: This solution works but the format needs to be culture sensitive. I believe that `-` will be replaced by `/` depending on the culture but it's not enough.

Comment: @LaurentDeCant you are correct and a way around this would be to hard code the format;
`.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd")` notice how the '-' are now "hard-coded" if this is a requirement?

Comment: I ended up using this solution.

Answer (score 2):

The "d" format specifier applies the short date pattern and "g" is a concatenation of the short date and short time patterns. So based on your results, you somehow have a short date pattern with time components in it. I can reproduce your results by setting such a short date pattern explicitly, like so:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString("g")); // 2008-05-11 00:00:00 00:00
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString("d")); // 2008-05-11 00:00:00
```

I think the real question is how you ended up with what looks like some very strange culture settings! I tried enumerating the set of supported cultures and looking for one whose short date format included time specifiers, like so:

```
foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Length))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{culture.Name}   {culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern}");
}
```

But in several hundred cultures I came up with nothing. So, can you find anything anywhere in your code that's building up a `CultureInfo` object and assigning it as the current culture? If yes, maybe there's a mistake in that code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  startDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.
    CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: Same result, still have those annoying `00:00:00`.